# AttributeError: 'DataModuleClass' object has no attribute 'training_dataset'

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to learn `PyTorch Lightning` by writing a very simple `DataModuleClass`. After `prepare_data()`, and `setup()` I am trying to check these functions are working or not. So, I am trying to get the `training` and `validation` dataset from `setup()`. But I am getting an error

```
AttributeError: 'DataModuleClass' object has no attribute 'training_dataset'
```

Code

```
def prepare_data(self):
    x = np.random.uniform(0, 10, 10)
    e = np.random.normal(0, self.sigma, len(x))
    
    # Making target or labels
    y = x + e
    
    # Marging x and e for 2 features
    X = np.transpose(np.array([x, e]))

    # Converting numpy array to Tensor
    self.x_train_tensor = torch.from_numpy(X).float().to(device)
    self.y_train_tensor = torch.from_numpy(y).float().to(device)
    
    training_dataset = TensorDataset(self.x_train_tensor, self.y_train_tensor)

    self.training_dataset = training_dataset

def setup(self):
    data = self.training_dataset
    self.train_data, self.val_data = random_split(data, [8, 2])
    return self.train_data, self.val_data
    
    
def train_dataloader(self):
    return DataLoader(self.train_data)

def val_dataloader(self):
    return DataLoader(self.val_data)
    
obj = DataModuleClass()
print(obj.setup())
```

Could you tell me why I am getting this error?

Comment: Please, update with the complete traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the way the code looks to me.

The variable `self.training_dataset` of the `DataModuleClass` is initiated in `prepare_data` and `setup` need it in the first line.

But you called `setup` without calling `training_dataset`.

If `prepare_data` is expected to be called every time you create a `DataModuleClass` object then it best to put `prepare_data` in `__init__`. Like

```
def __init__(self, other_params):
    ..... all your code previously in __init__
    self.prepare_data()  # put this in the last line of this function
```

But if you don't need that then you need to call `prepare_data` before `setup`

```
obj = DataModuleClass()
obj.prepare_data()
print(obj.setup())
```

Or put `prepare_data` in `setup` itself.

```
def setup(self):
    self.prepare_data()
    data = self.training_dataset
    self.train_data, self.val_data = random_split(data, [8, 2])
    return self.train_data, self.val_data
```

## Edit 1: See the actual value of `self.train_data` and `self.val_data`

The objects returned from `setup` are `torch.utils.data.dataset.Subset`.
There are basically 2 ways to get the tensors.

### 1. Treat them like lists

```
train_data, val_data = obj.setup()
print(train_data[0])
```

#### 2. Use for loop

```
train_data, val_data = obj.setup()
for data in train_data:
    print(data)
```

## Note

I'm not sure weather you'll get the tensors or `TensorDataset`. If it's the latter then use the same trick again, like

```
train_data, val_data = obj.setup()
train_tensor_data = train_data[0]
print(train_tensor_data[0])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have applied the first method and no error. But, I am getting `(<torch.utils.data.dataset.Subset object at 0x7f741346f8e0>, <torch.utils.data.dataset.Subset object at 0x7f741346fa00>)`. How can I see the exact value of `x, e, and y`? Like full tensor?